# How to add edges like this?

Tags: normal-map

[image]

In this image, especially on wings, there are many bumps, holes, etc., How to make them, average normal map is not doing it properly. Help.

Comment: You are basically asking some modelling techniques that may take months or years of practice for modelers to achieve. the easiest way to dig holes on surface is to extrude by pressing E. However the art of digging holes of desired shapes is one of the hardest to master, do not be troubled if you find it very confusing and difficult at first.

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called "Hard Surface Modeling". You find quite a lot of very detailed tutorials on that on the internet.